# Number of Digital Pins

Tags: arduino

Why "NUM_DIGITAL_PINS" returns 20 when I'm using Arduino Uno?

How can I get the number of digital pins in arduino?

I'm using Arduino 1.0.5 IDE

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wondering why the number is 20 when the Uno's digital pins goes from 0-13, is because the six analog pins can actually act as digital pins as well. So the total digital pins is 20.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, `NUM_DIGITAL_PINS` (all uppercase) is a macro. Its value is determined when you compile. It's in fact done by a literal text replacement. It doesn't "return" anything. Functions would return different values, but they tend to look more like `GetNumDigitalPins()`.